# In LightSwitch how do I remove the (x) at the top right of modal window? or change it's function?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-lightswitch

I Have a Modal window made in a LightSwitch 2012 project and I've been trying to find a way to remove the (x) that is made in the top right to close it. Either that or is there a method somewhere that I can edit to change some of it's function to better suit what I need?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If this is for the Silverlight client, it's as simple as one line of code (once you've added a ControlAvailable handler).

**C#:**

```
_window.ControlAvailable += (object s, ControlAvailableEventArgs e) => 
    {
        var window = (ChildWindow)e.Control;

        window.HasCloseButton = hasCloseButton;
    };
```

**VB:**

```
AddHandler _window.ControlAvailable, _
    Sub(s As Object, e As ControlAvailableEventArgs)
        Dim window = DirectCast(e.Control, ChildWindow)

        window.HasCloseButton = hasCloseButton
    End Sub
```

Comment: The question is tagged for c#;)

Comment: Thanks, I didn't notice that

Comment: Thanks for the answer, sorry I didn't see and respond until now